# Is it possible to add a row to a Google spreadsheet using the spreadsheet API without naming the columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In the following example (from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_a_list_of_spreadsheets) the columns have names (hours, ipm, items, name). Is it possible to do this without naming the columns (so that the values will just be placed in the first four columns)? If not, do the columns have any standard names I can use so that I don't have to name them myself? (I've tried using the names A, B, C, D and C1, C2, C3, C4, but they didn't work)

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">
  <gsx:hours>1</gsx:hours>
  <gsx:ipm>1</gsx:ipm>
  <gsx:items>60</gsx:items>
  <gsx:name>Elizabeth Bennet</gsx:name>
</entry>
```

Also, is there any way of seeing the worksheet Id (e.g. 'od6') of a worksheet? I can find the gid, and I found a formula which supposedly converts the gid to the worksheet Id, but I want to confirm that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

### CellFeed updates R1C1

You can update Cells using a cell reference, rather than a column name. CellFeed let you update using a cell reference.

Google example:
http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

### Append Row only - no insert

The is no method to "insert" a row between two exising rows, only to Append new rows at the end and update existing cells.

### convert od6 -> gid

People have posted undocumented ways to map from "od6" to "gid" style ID. [How to convert Google spreadsheet's worksheet string id to integer index (GID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290337/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheets-worksheet-string-id-to-integer-index-gid)

It is "undocumented", and so google may change it at any time.