# How can I get a list of sheets (name and "gid") in a Google spreadsheet using the Drive API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use Google Drive API (Python) to download some tabs of a spreadsheet file.
Is the gids information in the file's metadata?
What I am trying to do is (this may not be correct, please suggest) :

```
file_metadata = self.service.files().get(file_id=file_id).execute()
# in the following line, how can I get a download url with a gid (a tab in a spreadsheet file)
download_url = file_metadata.get('exportLinks')['text/csv']
# download the file.
```

Comment: >> download_url = file_metadata.get('exportLinks')['text/csv'] + '&gid=' + gid <<

I would like to get those gids from API too, along with the tab names.

Comment: Thanks @AMS, yea with names would be great!

Comment: @AMS, may I ask why we need to left move gid?

Comment: No need really. It just reads better when you can't insert a newline in a comment :P

Comment: what do you mean by `gid`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Google spreadsheet's worksheet string id to integer index (GID)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290337/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheets-worksheet-string-id-to-integer-index-gid)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an old visualization API URL

```
f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{doc_id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}'
```

to download a sheet by its name. I just posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526270/how-to-export-specific-sheet-using-new-v3-google-drive-api/73105761#73105761) together with code for the Google API Python library. This is also mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets) which links to the [Charts docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets?hl=en#gid) where it is shown how to do this with a `gid`. Alternatively, you can download all sheets by exporting the spreadsheet as an e.g. Excel file,

```py
class MimeTypes:
    EXCEL = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

drive_api.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=MimeTypes.EXCEL)
```

If you still want to go with getting sheets by `gid`, the `gid` is the `sheetId` in the Google Sheets API (see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet)).

And you should be able to use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to get all the sheets - and their corresponding `sheetId`s.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this seems to be a duplicate of [How to convert Google spreadsheet's worksheet string id to integer index (GID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290337/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheets-worksheet-string-id-to-integer-index-gid)

Here is the quick answer:

```
def to_gid(worksheet_id):
    return int(worksheet_id, 36) ^ 31578
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (perhaps due to the new google spreadsheets). For example, a worksheet_id of omlf5j6 is giving me 53609033112 using this method, when the actual gid is 1366234904

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Spreadsheet service in Google Apps Script.  It's not as convenient as having a direct API call, but at least it is possible:

1. Call the [`SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) method to open the spreadsheet using the Drive `file_id`.
2. Call the [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) method to retrieve a list of `Sheet` objects.
3. For each sheet, call the [`Sheet.getSheetId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId()) and [`Sheet.getSheetName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetName()) methods to get the name (which is what the spreadsheet user sees) and the sheetId (which is what needs to be provided in the `gid=` parameter when exporting).

You can use the recently-announced [`Apps Script Execution API`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) to provide a REST API for your Apps Script project, which you can then call in a similar manner to the Drive API.

Answer (score 0):

I have a radical idea: given that you intend to automate things a bit and already know (at least some) python, why not export data from the tabs you need to CSV files, download them, and then import as `pandas.DataFrame`s. After all, these data structures have been modeled after Google (and Excel) Sheets and are equally intuitive to use.