# Google Sheet gviz csv export - two column labels not exporting

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to export [this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQnp7RK-Ddq4wCjpHjmcnVEKood1U08kIfRGr8sDRoU/edit#gid=0) to a csv for use in a webmap using this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQnp7RK-Ddq4wCjpHjmcnVEKood1U08kIfRGr8sDRoU/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Sheet1

It works well, except that two of the column headers (lat, long) are not exporting and the column labels in the csv are blank. I tried to change the format of the cell from Automatic to Plain text, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Findings

It seems this is an issue with `gviz api` as there's an ongoing [**Google Issue** tracker report about it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156853537). You may want to click the **star** icon on the top left of issue report page to indicate that your are also affected by this issue.

### ***UPDATE***

As an alternative solution, you may try this way as this will export the same csv file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQnp7RK-Ddq4wCjpHjmcnVEKood1U08kIfRGr8sDRoU/export?format=csv&gid=0

***Reference:***
[Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64778214)

## Test

I did some quick tests on my end & after [manually downloading](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/49114?&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cdownload-a-copy-of-a-file) the sheet file as a Comma Separated Values (CSV) file from the Google Sheet UI & after using the **alternative solution**, there's no issue with missing cells. But when using the `gviz api` link, the issue occurs:

- [image]
- [image]

Comment: @Melissa My apologies for the inconvenience this issue has caused you. May I know if you're open to any alternative solution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The alternate export url works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you @SputnikDrunk2 it worked for me as well. Note: If anyone wants the specific sheet, should update gid=SHEET_ID (it's shown in the Google Sheets URL when the specific sheet is selected)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the column to 'Plain text' under the Format menu > Number, you should receive the data upon export.